# IBindingList does not support sorting issue

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview

I try to make sort in GridView. I take code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185890/how-to-sort-gridview?noredirect=1#comment30095005_20185890). And put it into `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event:

```
        private void УчасткиDataGridViewColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check which column is selected, otherwise set NewColumn to null.
        var newColumn =
            УчасткиDataGridView.Columns.GetColumnCount(
            DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) == 1 ?
            УчасткиDataGridView.SelectedColumns[0] : null;

        MessageBox.Show(УчасткиDataGridView.SelectedColumns.Count.ToString());
        var oldColumn = УчасткиDataGridView.SortedColumn;
        ListSortDirection direction;

        if (oldColumn != null)
        {
            // Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder. 
            if (oldColumn == newColumn &&
                УчасткиDataGridView.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                oldColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }

        if (newColumn == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a single column and try again.",
                "Error: Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            УчасткиDataGridView.Sort(newColumn, direction);
            newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
                direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
                SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        }
    }
```

But in line `УчасткиDataGridView.Sort(newColumn, direction);` i get exeption:

```
IBindingList does not support sorting
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic

Comment: If the `SupportsSorting` property is `false`, the method will not sort as the list source does not support sorting. You will have to either fix sorting yourself, or switch to another source that supports it.